org-export-to-ascii - standalone version?
I'm curious if there is a standalone binary of the org-export-to-ascii that is used in emacs to export... well org files to an ascii format.
I tried looking into the emacs documentation and could not find anything more about it, only that the command exists.

If you are asking if you can export an Org mode file to a text file from the command line, the answer is "yes". Try this command:
emacs --batch --file /path/to/org/file.org --eval "(org-ascii-export-to-ascii)"

or perhaps a bit more generically (but  you have to type a bit more and worry about escaping quotes):
 emacs --batch --file /path/to/org/file.org --eval "(org-export-to-file 'ascii \"myexported-foo2.txt\")"

In both cases, the output file is produced in the directory where the Org mode file is found. Note however that the second form allows you to set the file name to whatever you want; the first form just replaces the .org suffix with .txt.
